# Stopping Ubuntu locking the programme

Tags: unlock

How do I stop Ubuntu from clearing the screen and asking for an unlock password every few minutes of inactivity? I don't want it to ever "log me out" or whatever it's doing, however long a period of inactivity there might be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In `dash` or through Top Right Corner `Settings` icon go to `System settings`

Then in `Brightness and lock` , set the`Turn screen off..` to `Never` and `Lock` option to `Off` as in image here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply, so easy when you know how, much appreciated, have a good weekend.

Comment: @Basil- If the above solution worked , you can accept it as answer by ticking the Right-Tick sign left to answer :)